# on fbx export my model gets destroyed -> see image. why and howto resolve issue?

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx

After some minor changes on the model all of a sudden the mesh of the main body is copletely destroyed. The only things I changed were, that I connected two seperated parts of the mesh (with alt+M) and a bit of material, texture and UV changes.

Has anybody experienced this before? what could be the reason? 
all vertecies seem to still exist... the connections inbetween then is completely wrong tho.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using shapekeys? This could be part of the problem, after changing the geometry (joining meshes). This question is easier to answer, if you uploaded your file to www.blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: it alwyas was one mesh. there were just two not-connected parts inside the mesh, wich I connected with eachother.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5662" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5662/)

Comment: As the model is rigged any geometry edits (in particular merging with Alt+M) can cause behaviour like that.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is valid for **FBX 6.1 ASCII**.

You have non ASCII characters in shapekey names, which the fbx format apparently doesn't support.

[image: non ascii names]

<sup>*As it seems, two characters can't even be displayed in my Blender.*</sup>

Rename these shapekey names with ASCII characters only.
You also have some missing weights on *Body*.
[image: missing weights]

Exporting in *FBX 6.1 ASCII* works correctly.

Comment: that does not work.I have used that model with theese shapekeys for over half a year now without problems. When i rename them I still get that wierd export.

Comment: @SupraLP I have exported in *FBX 6.1 ASCII*. This must be the reason, why it required ASCII names to work. In FBX binary, I also get errors. I'd suggest, you use *FBX 6.1 ASCII*. Blender doesn't support FBX ASCII import, but most other applications do and I don't think you simply want to reimport it into Blender. If you explicitly need to export it as a binary FBX, then edit the question to receive a more fitting answer.